# How to calculate the mean/center frequency of the spectrum?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, continuous-signals

Assume that the Fourier Transform of $x(t)$ is $X(j\omega)$. And I want to calculate the $\bar{\omega}$ which is the center freqency in the spectrum ( the highest).

- And a classmate tells me  this formula $$ \bar{\omega} = \int \omega X(j\omega)\ d\omega$$ could be used to calculate the center frequency ? But it is the first moment, it seems that the result is mean frequency.
- Could anyone help me with this question?
- What is the mean and center frequency of the spectrum?

There is no solution in Alan's book.

---

**EDIT:**

**Maybe I did not state the center frequency clearly. I want to find out the frequency where the amplitude spectrum is biggest.**

Another situation: assume that the signal is discrete $x[n]$. So we could just compute a period $[-\pi, \pi]$. In this case, this formula could represent the *center frequency*?

Comment: @LaurentDuval Yep, I want to find out the frequency which amplitude is the *largest* one in the spectrum for the single-mount signal. What do you mean by *power tends to infinity*?

Comment: @LaurentDuval Yep, I have tried the code. Now I want to do the calculation. So I want reference for the formula. You could reply to me if you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT] If just want to compute the location of the maximum amplitude, you just have to compute the maximum. You can work in a more generic context, however. As you remarked, the notion of [center frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_frequency) is not evident. The notion of centroid could be more pertinent.

I assume that your signal is real (since you are talking about a maximum, not well defined in the complex domain). Since its amplitude spectrum is symmetric about $0$, this possible center of mass is useless, since it is the same for all real signals (the zero-frequency). More likely, one is looking at a more useful quantity, based on a one-sided spectrum:

$$\overline{\omega}_W = \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} \omega W(X(\omega))d\omega$$

where $W(X(\omega))$ is a weighting function that (may) depend on the spectrum $X$. The "mean" $\overline{\omega}_W $ will depend on the choice of $W$. A code was given in  the answer to [Finding the right measure to compare sound signals in the frequency domain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/27533/15892).

You can base it on an absolute value, or something else (positive).  But it is important to have a normalized weight: it should, somehow, sum to one, like for a traditional center of mass. The reason is scaling homogeneity. The mean should not change if you multiply every $X(w)$ by the same quantity.

For orthogonal transforms, based on the energy conservation:

$$ \int [x(t)|^2dt = \int [X(\omega)|^2d\omega $$

it is very common to use a mean/center definition based on an energetic weight, ie 
a square of the absolute spectrum. So  every often, the mean frequency is defined as:

$$\overline{\omega}_2 = \frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}^+} \omega|X(\omega)|^2d\omega}{\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}|X(\omega)|^2d\omega}\,.$$

This choice is very sensitive when dealing with time/frequency location uncertainty related to the [Weyl-Pauli-Heisenberg inequalities](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/169_04_JIPAM/169_04.pdf).

But you can use other $L_p$ norms, with:

$$\overline{\omega}_p = \frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}^+} \omega|X(\omega)|^pd\omega}{\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}|X(\omega)|^pd\omega}\,.$$

As $p\to\infty$, this estimator converges to the location of a maximum, as demonstrated in [Metric Spaces: Why $L_\infty$ selects the maximum value](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/29193/15892).

When $p=1$, this is called the [spectral centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_centroid), or "brightness" (of sound), or simply "centre of gravity of amplitudes". It is described with other moments in [Chapter 6.1 Spectral shape description](http://recherche.ircam.fr/equipes/analyse-synthese/peeters/ARTICLES/Peeters_2003_cuidadoaudiofeatures.pdf). When $p=2$, this is sometimes called the [power spectral centroid](http://web.arch.usyd.edu.au/~densil/sos/sonifications/spectralmoments/spectralmoments.html).

I have not found yet useful references for other powers (still searching).

Comment: Yep. I just use MATLAB to test a signal. The result is the last formular you give. Thank you!

Comment: But why is  $\bar{w}_1$ not true? Why amplitude does not make sense?

Comment: Hello! I still have a question. Could you discuss with me in the chat?http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56145/the-mean-frequency Thanks!:)