# Energy of a signal

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum

Suppose that $E(k)$ be the energy distribution of a signal in spectral domain with a finite total energy. Is there anyway to concentrates all the energy of signal around a specific point?

Comment: Is the "specific point" that you are thinking about in the frequency domain or in the time domain? Are nonlinear methods acceptable or are you thinking about linear filtering only?

Comment: Bandpass filter with a very narrow passband plus normalization to the original level?

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed. Bear with me, I am in a mood for a long explanation.

Remember physics of motion, and how one concentrates the information related to the motion of an object on its center of mass, that capture a unique point from a *distribution of mass*.

A similar reasoning can be applied to positive quantities $q(k)$ (like energy) whose sum is finite. Thus, you can normalize them to  unitless and positive quantities  $q(k)/\sum_k q(k)$ that sums to $1$, similarly to probability distributions.

There, to characterize or summarize distributions with a few values, you can use the notion of moments (probably borrowed from the same [moment notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(physics)) in physics) or cumulants:

> an expression involving the product of a distance and another physical
>   quantity, and in this way it accounts for how the physical quantity is
>   located or arranged

The $\alpha$ moments $m_q(c,\alpha)$ of  $q(\cdot)$, centered around $c$, are given by:

$$m_q(c,\alpha) = \sum_l (l-c)^\alpha \frac{q(l)}{\sum_k q(k)} =  \frac{\sum_l (l-c)^\alpha q(l)}{\sum_k q(k)} \,.$$

Here, the $q$s can be interpreted as unit-sum weights, affecting the "distance" $(l-c)^\alpha$ (more a power-norm, to be honest).

So, in discrete signal processing, using orthogonal or energy-preserving transformations, it is customary to take $q(\cdot)$ as the energy of signal samples, either in the time or the frequency domain. And $l,k$ are discrete indices. For distribution location, we usually set $\alpha=1$.

So for finite-energy signal $s[n]$, you can define its "center mass" in time with:

$$ \overline{s} =\frac{\sum_n n |s[n]|^2}{\sum_n |s[n]|^2}$$
and in frequency by:
$$ \overline{E} =\frac{\sum_k k E[k]}{\sum_k E[k]}$$
but beware in summing on positive frequencies only for a meaninful interpretation for real signals (as spectra are symmetric, and would yield a center of frequency mass at $0$).

To illustrate it with a picture and a Matlab code (using [FFTR.m](http://www.laurent-duval.eu/Documents-Common/FFTR.m)):

[image: Center of mass, in time and frequency spectrum]

```
clear all;
timeStart = 0;
timeStop = 1;
nPoint = 1024;
time = linspace(timeStart,timeStop,nPoint)';
dataFreqSampling = 1/median(diff(time));
dataFreq = 56;
dataSpread  = 0.2;
data = sin(2*pi*dataFreq*time).*exp(-((time-(timeStop-timeStart)/16)/(dataSpread)).^2);

dataEnergy = data.^2;
timeCenterOfMass = sum(time.*dataEnergy)/sum(dataEnergy);

[fftR,fftAxe] = FFTR(data,1/dataFreqSampling);
dataEnergyFreq = fftR.^2;
freqCenterOfMass = sum(fftAxe.*dataEnergyFreq)/sum(dataEnergyFreq);

figure;clf;
subplot(2,1,1);hold on
plot(time,data);axis tight;
plot(timeCenterOfMass,0,'o');axis tight;grid on
xlabel('Time (s)');ylabel('Amplitude')
legend('Time Signal','Center of mass')

subplot(2,1,2);hold on
plot(fftAxe,fftR);axis tight;
plot(freqCenterOfMass,0,'o');axis tight;grid on
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');ylabel('Amplitude')
legend('Frequency Spectrum','Center of mass')
```

More details about:

- moment names in statistics: [Higher-order cumulant and moment names beyond variance, skewness and kurtosis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/188281/83945)
- [How to calculate the mean/center frequency of the spectrum?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/38650/15892)
- [What is meant by “spectral moment”?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/what-is-meant-by-spectral-moment/1363#1363)

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand well your response. In question I meant for example transition of whole the energy around a specific point. Consider a gaussian like spreading of a signal around a point which has energy equal to the original signal.

Comment: I do apologize, I knew I could spread confusion. Yet, I don't really get what you mean by "transition of whole the energy", "a gaussian like spreading". I think an illustration could be informative (on both sides :)

Comment: No problem @Laurent. :)

Comment: I have added a picture and some code, please to intereact

Answer (score 1):

Without understanding the context of your question, you might consider a Class C power amplifier used in broad cast radio.

It uses a high Q  resonator with nonlinear feedback. It is not  a DSP technique but does concentrate energy if you have a loose definition of input.

The best you can do with a linear process is to excite a high Q resonance.